# How do I mount an LVM partition?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I was trying to update Java and I used a star to make sure it was removed completely not realizing it would mess up everything

I used

```
apt-get remove java*
```

this was on the Ubuntu 16.0 or something server. I now have sysrcd or System Rescue CD on the server and I'm attempting to get my old files back to put them on a new server and reload the sysrcd server back to Ubuntu. However I can't seem to figure out how to use the mount system.

I've tried running

```
fdisk -l
```

and I get

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x04a5ca62

Device    Boot     Start       End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1 *         2048      4095      1024  83 Linux
/dev/sda2           6142 468860927 234427393   5 Extended
/dev/sda5           6144   2004991    999424  83 Linux
/dev/sda6        2007040 468860927 233426944  8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-root: 221.6 GiB, 237879951360 bytes, 464609280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg-tmp: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg-swap: 88 MiB, 92274688 bytes, 180224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I'm not sure which drive to mount or how to mount it. Can someone help?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the mistake you made and what happens when the booting attempts but fails?  Please add these details to your question.

Comment: I have edited the details, look at the original post.

Comment: You may be able to repair your installation by reversing your `apt-get remove` command.  Have a look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.  You should be able to reinstall each of the packages that were removed.

Comment: Uhh, remember I'm not able to access those files right? I'm trying to mount the drive to get access to those files...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A few more steps are needed when mounting an `LVM` partition vs. a non-LVM partition.

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2   #This step may or may not be required.
sudo pvscan                 #Use this to verify your LVM partition(s) is/are detected.
sudo vgscan --mknodes       #Scans for LVM Volume Group(s)
sudo vgchange -ay           #Activates LVM Volume Group(s)
sudo lvscan                 #Scans for available Logical Volumes
sudo mount /dev/YourVolGroup00/YourLogVol00 /YourMountPoint
```

Comment: I'm on the rescue cd like I mentioned before, it's a little different from Linux. It doesn't have the 'apt-get' program installed.

Comment: Are you able to boot using an `Ubuntu Live CD` instead?

Comment: I am not able to, no.

Comment: If you have your installation CD/DVD, you can boot into Rescue mode.  Is this an option?  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-boot-ubuntu-linux-rescue-mode/

Comment: No, I am using an unmanaged dedicated host from www.wholesaleinternet.net.

Comment: I have run out of helpful ideas.

Comment: I'm sure apt-get would work on the system, I'm just having trouble finding out how to get it on the system.

Comment: Have you tried skipping the `apt-get` step and running `pvscan` etc.?

Comment: Your rescue CD [already has LVM support](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Detailed-packages-list), there's no need to install anything.

Comment: Thank you Stephen and Timothy! Skipping the apt-get part worked and I now have access to my files!!

Comment: Got problem after replaced CD module by old HDD. That HDD have previous linux mind with lvm. These speps works for me.

Comment: For anybody here in 2021, this helped me out on Debian 10 mounting an encrypted SSD.

Comment: Update /etc/fstab : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-an-lvm-volume-partition-command/

Comment: adding --mknodes to the vgscan command was what solved my issue. Going to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is also gui method using [gnome-disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)

- choose disk and paritition
- click "More actions" button with cogs icon
- open : "Edit Mount Options" menu item
- Turn off User Defaults because
- check box "Mount at system startup"