# How to restore missing /var/lib/dpkg/status file?

Tags: ubuntu

Recently I messed up my operating system (Ubuntu 16) and I am running a rescue cd to retrieve my files. At the moment the system does not have aptitude on the system, making it very hard to [mount the system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition?noredirect=1#) to get those said files back. I have managed to find a .deb file for aptitude but yet my luck runs out again. In order to install it I need to run a `dpkg` install command. Which just so happens to be broke as well, at first I was getting  `/var/lib/dpkg/status`  was missing, I placed a file in that place and it still didn't work. I started googling how to replace it and people suggested `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`. That doesn't exist, I've also looked in `/var/backups`, doesn't exist either. I'm running out of ideas and I really need my data back.
Please note: I am on an unmanaged dedicated host limited to this one rescue cd, I am not able to ask them for help or ask them to place a different cd in the drive.

Comment: The closest you can get is the `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` file.

Comment: What you say "I placed a file in that place", do you mean an empty file?  What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: heemayl: That file doesn't exists, like I've stated.

Julie: I just placed an empty file, yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was misconstrued, and as a result the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question as stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're focusing on the wrong problem. System Rescue CD is based on Gentoo, not a Debian derivative, so there's no need for `aptitude` etc. In fact it already has [all the tools you need](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Detailed-packages-list) to mount your file systems; just start with the `pvscan` step in the answer given to your other question.

Comment: i downvoted your answer because the OP stated ` I am not able to ask them for help or ask them to place a different cd in the drive.`

Comment: @fpmurphy1 the OP already has System Rescue CD in the drive (see the linked question), so I'm not sure I understand your reasoning.

Comment: After trying the answer on my other question it worked and I now have access to my files! Thanks a ton!